# Guest Login Vulnerability (CVE-2017-8900) - 16.04 is still using upstart?

Tags: 16.04, upstart, systemd-logind

I recently read about a login screen vulnerability that affected 16.10 and 17.04, but not 16.04. Apparently the reason for this is that 16.04 still uses Upstart to handle the user session, whereas the affected releases use systemd.

Until now, I had the understanding that 16.04 was when everything was supposed to cut over to systemd, but it looks like there are still some upstart <strike>migrations happening</strike> parts in use? Just out of curiosity, I can see that there are both upstart and systemd are running on 16.04 desktop, but not server.

Does anyone have a good explanation as to what parts are still using upstart in 16.04 (as well as 16.10 and 17.x, if any)? From what I had read about Ubuntu switching to systemd, it was seeming like an all-or-nothing switch-over with 16.04, versus <strike>a migration</strike> development that's still in progress. Since 16.04 server isn't running it, it seems like only `lightdm` or other desktop components still need upstart?

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/ubuntu-guest-sessions-login-disabled
http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-8900.html

Comment: "it looks like there are still some upstart migrations happening" It does? Where?

Comment: The fact that upstart is still being used in 16.04 means that the migration from upstart to systemd is still happening, at least as far as that release is concerned.

Comment: Uh, no. It does mean that the migration was frozen at that stage for 16.04.

Comment: Rather than debating the semantics of development terminology, you could elaborate on that and try to provide an answer?

Comment: I could, but if you and I understand different things from a given statement, what's the point? Right now, all I see is a wild claim that Ubuntu is still doing some "migrations" in 16.04 systems.

Comment: I edited the question to remove mention of migration, since that seems to have derailed my question. With that out of the way, would you care to provide an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "migrations" happening in 16.04. The migration from systemd to Upstart for [PID1 happened in 15.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes#Boot_and_service_management), and for [user sessions in 16.10.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YakketyYak/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Desktop) Upstart handles [only graphical user sessions](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2016-July/039465.html) in the releases from 15.04 to 16.04 (inclusive).

[Booting with Upstart was offered](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Switching_init_systems) for 15.04, but is a try-at-your-own-risk for newer releases.